# How to know the price of the day of ETH in USD by Oracles?

Tags: ether, oracles

Consider in a contract the payer intends to pay recipient `ETH` based on `USD` (ex. the salary is 1 `USD` but paid by `ETH`).

So, if today contract needs to know equivalent value of 1 `ETH` in `USD` exactly at time of payment.

For this, contract needs to access to some external sources to know the price of the day of `ETH` in `USD`.

I want to use ex. [THIS WEB SITE](https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/ETHUSD/) as data-source. How can I fetch the price of `ETH` from this website as an ex. integer value ?

Is there a sample of such ***contract*** / ***data-source*** as an ***example*** ?

Comment: I think this sample contract: [link](http://docs.oraclize.it/#ethereum-quick-start) does this query.